# Trying to find out the resumption rate of the students between T-1, T & T+1 (T= term)

Tags: sql, mysql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SRIAC.png) : sample Dataset

Problem Statement: I am trying to find out the resumption rate of the students between T-1, T & T+1

- Expected Output for consecutive terms
- Student : ABC :  Paused in T2 2023

  - Resumed in T 3 2023
  - Paused in t4 2023
  - Resumed in T 1 2024
- Student XYZ : No Resumptions

Code for creating test data --

```
create  table test_student (student varchar(25), Term char (2),
year int, Subject varchar(20));
insert into test_student
values ("abc","t1","2021","sub1"),
("abc","t2","2021","sub2"),
("abc","t3","2021",""),
("abc","t4","2021",""),
("abc","t1","2022",""),
("abc","t2","2022","sub3"),
("abc","t3","2022",""),
("abc","t4","2022",""),
("abc","t1","2023","sub4"),
("abc","t2","2023",""),
("abc","t3","2023","sub5"),
("abc","t4","2023",""),
("abc","t1","2024","sub 6"),
("XYZ","t1","2021","subl"),
("XYZ","t2","2021","sub2"),
("XYZ","t3","2021",""),
("XYZ","t4","2021",""),
("XYZ","t1","2022",""),
("XYZ","t2","2022",""),
("XYZ","t3","2022","sub3"),
("XYZ","t4","2022",""),
("XYZ","t1","2023",""),
("XYZ","t2","2023","sub4"),
("XYZ","t3","2023","sub5");
```

Comment: Sample dataset must be provided according to [Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055) (#5), **and it must be accompanied by the desired output** (#3),

Comment: Define strictly what is "paused" and "resumed". For example, "paused is - subject is not set in year N but is set in both N-1 and N+1". Define what if for a year N there is no a row N+1. And so on... you understand your task completely (I hope), unlike us.